# "consolidate on" or "consolidate into"?

Tags: prepositions

At work today, I wrote "we have several XXs. We should *consolidate on* one XX."

A colleague corrected it to *consolidate into*.

Which is correct?

I'm English and my colleague is American, if that makes a difference. Googlefight ranks them as about equal.

*UPDATE*
The actual XX is fairly technical and obscure so I'll use *algorithm* as a stand-in.

We use several algorithms for calculating the score. 
--several paragraphs later--
We should consolidate on a single algorithm.

The separation between the problem statement and the solution leads me to believe that skipping the preposition won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there confusion between consolidation and standardisation?

- Consolidation combines or joins several things together *into* one *solid* thing.
- Standardisation chooses one of several things and makes everyone use that one unchanged thing. Use of the other (now non-standard) things is then discontinued.

Perhaps "**standardise on a single new† algorithm**".

†*substitute "composite", "consolidated" for "new" according to needs or taste.*

Comment: _Selection_ doesn't quite sound right to me. The thing we want to consolidate on/into is new so it's more than _standardise_. It's 'create a new thing and standardise on that'.

Comment: Agreed, answer updated. I'm not sure if you thought of standardise before or after I edited that part of my answer. Try "Standardise on a new algorithm" or "Standardise on a composite algorithm" or even "Standardise on a consolidated algorithm"

Comment: I saw your answer about 29secs after you updated. I like your latest suggestion and will go with standardise. But, since this is America, I will spell it wrong.

Answer (score 2):

*We should consolidate them into one XX.*

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends upon the situation. The big entity consolidates *on* small entity and small entity consolidates *into* the big entity in the accounting terms. Safest way is just to use consolidate and omit the preposition.

Comment: Neither item is conceptually bigger or smaller.